# DataTables - PHP/AJAX Multisearch dropdown

Tags: php, ajax, datatables, dropdown

I have my datatables and i want to filter them with dropdowns:

[image]

**With the method that is being done, only `"Country"` is being fetched and filtered successfully.**

**I want to create two filter options for `"Country, City"`**

Comment: "_I want to create two filter options_" -  What is preventing you from adding these 2 other filters? What is the actual problem you are facing? Also, can you show the relevant (minimally required) code and data in the question itself, instead of only providing a link? If this is a [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) question, you can remove the ambiguous `datatable` tag and use `datatables` instead.

Comment: In case it may help: Have you looked at examples such as [this one](https://datatables.net/examples/plug-ins/range_filtering.html) which shows two filter inputs working together?

Comment: Hello @andrewJames , im learning the basics of PHP. Spend some time make this work with additional filters, couldn't make it. I uploaded the full source code because i'd like to see the solution as is. To be honest im not quite sure how to fully separate (due to fetch.php) i think it would take too much space, Thank you for your answers, they been extremely helpful

Comment: I also seen the two inputs filtering a range but it is not quite what i want to do. All i want to do is to fetch the records from the database in a dropdown menu, so the user can select and filter multiple records which will result in live ajax for the datatables

Comment: OK - understood, thanks. If your specific problem is how to create multiple JavaScript/DataTables column filters, then the PHP side may well be irrelevant. You can use [hard-coded HTML table data](https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/dom.html) for that. That can help with the "minimal" part of a [mre].

Comment: If your problem is the "fetching from PHP" part, then the DataTables piece is the irrelevant piece. But without knowing where you are stuck, it's guesswork on our part.

Comment: Hello again, andrewJames, thanks a lot for your time & attention, to be honest i should focus more on the basics in general. I tried to make it from PHP to minimal HTML but couldn't do it, so i updated full github repo, if you could help it would mean the world to me. All i want to do is put custom dropdown filters for my datatables. Thank you again :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a minimal approach which uses some hard-coded test data embedded in the demo, and which uses two drop-down lists to control filtering.

You can run the demo by clicking on the "run code snippet" button. You can also read the comments I added to the HTML and JavaScript in the demo.

The demo is *not a complete solution*.

1. It does not integrate with PHP - it purely focuses on how to perform the filtering in the DataTable.
2. There is no relationship between the two drop-downs. When you choose a value for the first drop-down, the list of available values in the second drop-down does not change. Building that feature would be a more advanced topic. There are questions on Stack Overflow covering that, elsewhere, I believe.

```js
// This is hard-coded test data. Normally, this would 
// be provided by your PHP code. But using this here
// helps us to create a minimal self-contained demo:
var dataSet = [
    {
      "name": "Tiger Nixon",
      "position": "System Architect",
      "salary": "$320,800",
      "start_date": "2011/04/25",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "5421"
    },
    {
      "name": "Donna Snider",
      "position": "Customer Support",
      "salary": "$112,000",
      "start_date": "2011/01/25",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4226"
    },
    {
      "name": "Cedric Kelly",
      "position": "Senior Javascript Developer",
      "salary": "$433,060",
      "start_date": "2012/03/29",
      "office": "Edinburgh",
      "extn": "6224"
    },
    {
      "name": "Airi Satou",
      "position": "Accountant",
      "salary": "$162,700",
      "start_date": "2008/11/28",
      "office": "Tokyo",
      "extn": "5407"
    },
    {
      "name": "Brielle Williamson",
      "position": "Integration Specialist",
      "salary": "$372,000",
      "start_date": "2012/12/02",
      "office": "New York",
      "extn": "4804"
    }
  ];

$(document).ready(function() {

var table = $('#example').DataTable( {
  data: dataSet,
  columns: [
    { title: "Name", data: "name" },
    { title: "Office", data: "office" },
    { title: "Position", data: "position" },
    { title: "Start date", data: "start_date" },
    { title: "Extn.", data: "extn" },
    { title: "Salary", data: "salary" }
  ],
  initComplete: function () {
    // This demo uses two columns: index 1 (office) and index 2 (position):
    this.api().columns( [1, 2] ).every( function () {

      var column = this;

      // this locates the drop-down for the relevant column using the 
      // 'data-col-idx' attribute defined in each drop-down:
      var select = $("select[data-col-idx='" + column.index() + "']");

      // this builds a sorted list of column values for each drop-down, 
      // and then adds that data to each drop-down:
      column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( val ) {
        select.append( '<option value="' + val + '">' + val + '</option>' )
      } );

      // this adds "change" events to each drop-down, and when the events fire,
      // there is logic to filter each affected column:
      select.on( 'change', function () {
        // get the selected value from the drop-down:
        var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex( $(this).val() );
        // use that value to filter the column data in the table:
        column.search( val ? '^' + val + '$' : '', true, false ).draw();
      } );

    });
  }

} ); 

} );
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Demo</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/js/jquery.dataTables.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.22/css/jquery.dataTables.css">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://datatables.net/media/css/site-examples.css">

</head>

<body>

<div style="margin: 20px;">

    <!-- each drop-down starts with one drop-down option (an empty value) needed to 
         reset the filter back to "all values". It also uses data-col-idx attributes 
         to allow each drop-down to be matched to a column in the DataTable            -->
    <select data-col-idx="1" style="margin: 10px; width:150px;"><option value=""></option></select>
    <select data-col-idx="2" style="margin: 10px; width:250px;"><option value=""></option></select>

    <table id="example" class="display dataTable cell-border" style="width:100%">
    </table>

</div>



</body>
</html>
```